cannot run Flink job with flink run
I am running a Flink app using
python -m app.job

job.py is a module in directory app
It runs fine and processes data with PyFlink.
However, the job is not submitted to a local cluster (Docker) that i am running, and i think this needs to be done with flink run instead.
I had to install Flink from the binary in the container that has the Flink client, i.e. the app.job.py and there is Flink now in that container. However, both from the Dockerfile of the Flink client and when i open a bash shell in that container, i cannot run:
flink run -py app.job

There is an error message:
usage: PythonDriver [-py <pythonFile>] [-pym <pythonModule>]
     -py,--python <pythonFile>        Python script with the program entry
                                      point. The dependent resources can be
                                      configured with the `--pyFiles` option.
     -pym,--pyModule <pythonModule>   Python module with the program entry
                                      point. This option must be used in
                                      conjunction with `--pyFiles`.

Any idea what i am doing wrong here?
I added flink in the Dockerfile because Flink was not available, although had installed PyFlink with the apache-flink package.
COPY flink_pkg/flink-1.18.1-bin-scala_2.12.tgz /opt
RUN tar -xzf /opt/flink-1.18.1-bin-scala_2.12.tgz -C /opt/ && \
    rm /opt/flink-1.18.1-bin-scala_2.12.tgz && \
    mv /opt/flink-1.18.1 /opt/flink
COPY libs/flink-sql-connector-kafka-3.1.0-1.18.jar /opt/flink/lib/
ENV FLINK_HOME="/opt/flink"
ENV PATH="$FLINK_HOME/bin:$PATH"

UPDATE:
After updating the Dockerfile and entrypoint.sh and with the below proeject structure:
flink_app
-> Dockerfile
-> entrypoint.sh
-> flink_job.py
libs
-> connector jars..
docker-compose.yml

My flink_app Dockerfile is:
FROM python:3.10-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get -y update; apt-get -y install \
    curl \
    gcc \
    openjdk-11-jdk-headless \
    procps \
    netcat \
    wget \
    tar

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on \
    PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
    POETRY_VERSION=1.7.1 \
    POETRY_HOME="/opt/poetry" \
    POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1 \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE=false \
    VIRTUAL_ENV="/venv" \
    JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"

ENV PATH="$POETRY_HOME/bin:$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:/opt/ml/code:$PATH"

ENV PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"

# prepare virtual env
RUN python -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -

COPY ./pyproject.toml ./poetry.lock ./
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache poetry install --no-root
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache poetry install --only-root



COPY flink_app/ ./flink_app/
COPY libs/ ./libs/
COPY flink_app/entrypoint.sh ./

ENV PYTHONPATH="/app:$PYTHONPATH"

# For Flink local checkpoints
RUN mkdir -p /app/checkpoints && \
    chmod -R 755 /app/checkpoints


ENV FLINK_VERSION=1.18.1

RUN wget https://downloads.apache.org/flink/flink-${FLINK_VERSION}/flink-${FLINK_VERSION}-bin-scala_2.12.tgz \
    && tar -xzf flink-${FLINK_VERSION}-bin-scala_2.12.tgz -C /opt/ \
    && rm flink-${FLINK_VERSION}-bin-scala_2.12.tgz

ENV PATH=$PATH:/opt/flink-${FLINK_VERSION}/bin


# Entrypoint
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]

My docker-compose.yml file is:
version: '3.7'
name: test-flink-streaming

networks:
  standard:
    driver: bridge


volumes:
  kafka: null
  mariadb_data: null

services:
  # Zookeeper
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
    networks:
      - standard

  # Kafka
  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: bitnami/kafka:latest
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9094:9094"
    volumes:  # for storing the messages
      - kafka:/var/lib/kafka/data
    hostname: kafka
    networks:
      - standard
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID=0
      - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=controller,broker
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=0@kafka:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
      - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS=action-logs:1:1
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093,EXTERNAL://:9094
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9094
      - KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer=DEBUG,org.apache.kafka.clients.producer=DEBUG


  log_simulator:
    container_name: log_simulator
    image: log-simulator:local
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: log_simulator/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - standard
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    command: sh -c "sleep 20 && python log_simulator/log_generator.py"  


  jobmanager:
    image: flink:1.18.1-scala_2.12
    container_name: flink_jobmanager
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    command: jobmanager
    volumes:
      - ./libs/flink-sql-connector-kafka-3.1.0-1.18.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-sql-connector-kafka-3.1.0-1.18.jar
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
    networks:
      - standard
    depends_on:
      - kafka

  taskmanager:
    image: flink:1.18.1-scala_2.12
    container_name: flink_taskmanager
    volumes:
      - ./libs/flink-sql-connector-kafka-3.1.0-1.18.jar:/opt/flink/lib/flink-sql-connector-kafka-3.1.0-1.18.jar
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - jobmanager
    command: taskmanager
    environment:
      - |
        FLINK_PROPERTIES=
        jobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager
        taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 2
    networks:
      - standard

  # Flink app
  flink_app:
    container_name: flink_app
    image: flink-app:local
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: flink_app/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - standard
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
      - kafka
    environment:
      KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "kafka:9092"

And my entrypoint.sh is:
#!/bin/bash

wait_for_jobmanager() {
    echo "Waiting for Flink JobManager to be ready..."
    while ! nc -z jobmanager 8081; do
      sleep 1
    done
    echo "Flink JobManager is ready."
}

wait_for_jobmanager


echo "Starting Simple Flink Job..."
#python -m flink_app.flink_job
flink run -py /app/flink_app/flink_job.py

The error message i am getting now is:
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:8081

Caused by: org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:8081


Perhaps this example will help: https://github.com/apache/flink-playgrounds/tree/master/pyflink-walkthrough

I have read many people struggling to get flink up and running. Are you constrained to using it? or just trying it because its what you found?

@DavidAnderson Which part are you referring to?

@SRosam The challenge is having PyFlink running locally using Docker, in combination with other services e.g. Kafka and perhaps with DBs like MySQL.

I shared that link thinking it might help to start from a working example that combines pyflink + kafka in docker.

@DavidAnderson Thanks for the link. It is quite similar to what i am doing but it still does not work in my case. See my updated question above for more info.

Have you tried this?
flink run -py app.job.py

The examples I've seen always include the full name of the python file.

I have provided an update above. Maybe it has to do with how i am structuring my app in the Dockerfile and where Flink is installed?

I have submitted a simple Flink job that runs on my local (Docker) Flink cluster but when i am trying to run another Flink job that is supposed to read from Kafka i am getting this error: Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: class org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer is not an instance of org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer Any idea what would cause that?
I am running:
docker-compose exec -e KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS="kafka:9092" jobmanager flink run -py /opt/app/job.py
